# how do i parse my input/output data to a model made using keras?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, regression, keras

I am currently using keras to train a regression network.

The network is build, but I am not sure on how I should pass my input and output data to the model.

Both the input and output is stored as list of numpy arrays. 
The numpy arrays in input list has a shape of (400 rows, *y* columns). 
And the numpy arrays in the output has a shape of (*y* rows, 13 columns)

The input dimension of the network is 400 and output is 13.

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/sequential/).

```
fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=[], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)
```

> x: input data, as a Numpy array or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs).
>
> y: labels, as a Numpy array.

y is not labels in this case, but raw data aswell. But how do ensure that the model. knows that is shall take each columns for input and row as output, do it for all the entries in the list...

Just parsing the data without doing anything to it gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_datapreprocess_mfcc_extraction_rnn.py", line 167, in <module>
    model.fit(train_set_data,train_set_output,verbose=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 620, in fit
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1034, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 961, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='model input')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 51, in standardize_input_data
    '...')
Exception: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 270 arrays: [array([[ -1.52587891e-04,   3.05175781e-05,  -1.52587891e-04,
         -5.18798828e-04,   3.05175781e-05,  -3.96728516e-04,
          1.52587891e-04,   3.35693359e-04,  -9.15527344e-05,
          3.3...
```

Code:

```
print "Training!"
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=400, init="normal"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
model.fit(train_set_data,train_set_output,verbose=1)
```

Comment: What does you compile step look like? After you define the model you need to compile it. I'm the compile step you may need to use categorical cross entropy

Comment: ....? I am not sure i understand how that is related? 
isn't that part of the model.fit step?

Comment: Look at the example section in the link you list above

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. Yes..  why a categorical entropy? I use a sgd optimizer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reshape your training input by tranposing the numpy array, i.e.

```
x = np.transpose(x)
```

Then you should have your training input in shape of (number_samples, number_features), which is the required format of input. Your training output is already in the right format.